# Find pid using python by grepping two variables

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am trying to find pid of a oracle process by using below command

ps -ef | grep pmon | grep orcl | grep -v grep

When trying to use python 
oracle_pid = os.system("echo `ps -ef | grep pmon | grep %s | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`" %(oracle_sid))
print(oracle_pid)

it is printing 0 as value

Any suggestions on how to achieve just the pid as output?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.system):

> (...) On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process encoded in the format specified for wait() (...)

And since your program runs correctly, it returns 0.

To get the desired output, you must use the `subprocess` module (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
import subprocess
oracle_pid = subprocess.check_output("ps -ef | grep pmon | grep %s | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True).strip().decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the output is adding characters>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output("ps -ef | grep pmon | grep orcl | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
b'21648\n'
>>>

Comment: Updated the answer to remove the newline and convert to string. If the answer is good, please mark it as correct and upvote it!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply !!!
The command works but it is adding extra characters

> > > import subprocess
> > >       subprocess.check_output("ps -ef | grep pmon | grep orcl | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
> > >       b'21648\n'

Comment: If you need to comment on an answer, then use the 'add a comment' link. Do not post a comment as an answer.